# Issue how to take xml from blob in oracle with readonly permission on DB

Tags: xml, oracle, blob

Hi Could you please help with the issue.

There is access to read only in DB(only select).Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit.
The table contains a lot of fields and one **ADVICE_DOC BLOB**;
The question is how to take xml document from blob field.

Thank you

Comment: Try, `select xmltype(DBMS_XSLPROCESSOR.READ2CLOB('oracle_directrory','file_name')) from dual;` 
where oracle_directrory is createdb by `create directory oracle_directrory as 'path_to_disk_dir'`

Comment: @ArkadiuszŁukasiewicz That will work if the file is stored in the file system - however, the OP states that the data is in a blob field and they only have read-only access (so presumably cannot write out to the file system).

Comment: Please provide more information - the DDL for the table, and what *exactly* you mean by "read-only access". Does this mean you're not allowed to perform INSERT / UPDATE statements, only SELECTs? Does the table live in a different schema? (and please don't add additional information in comments - use the *Edit* button to edit your question instead).

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION BLOB_TO_CLOB( b BLOB )
RETURN CLOB
IS
  c            CLOB;
  n            NUMBER    := 1;
  w   CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := 32767;
  len CONSTANT NUMBER    := LENGTH( b );
BEGIN
  IF b IS NULL THEN
    RETURN NULL;
  END IF;
  IF len = 0 THEN
    RETURN EMPTY_CLOB();
  END IF;
  DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c, TRUE );
  WHILE ( n + w <= len ) LOOP
    DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c, w, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( b, w, n ) ) );
    n := n + w;
  END LOOP;
  DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c, len - n + 1, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( b, len - n + 1, n ) ) );
  RETURN c;
END;
/
```

Then you should be able to use:

```
SELECT XMLType( BLOB_TO_CLOB( blob_column ) ) AS xml
FROM   your_table;
```

Or with only read-only access you could do:

```
VARIABLE cur REFCURSOR;

DECLARE
  b            BLOB;
  c            CLOB;
  n            NUMBER    := 1;
  w   CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := 32767;
  len          NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT blob_column
  INTO   b
  FROM   your_table
  WHERE  id = 1;

  IF b IS NOT NULL THEN
    len := LENGTH( b );
    IF len = 0 THEN
      c := EMPTY_CLOB();
    ELSE
      DBMS_LOB.CREATETEMPORARY( c, TRUE );
      WHILE ( n + w <= len ) LOOP
        DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c, w, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( b, w, n ) ) );
        n := n + w;
      END LOOP;
      DBMS_LOB.WRITEAPPEND( c, len - n + 1, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2( DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR( b, len - n + 1, n ) ) );
    END IF;
  END IF;

  OPEN :cur FOR
  SELECT XMLType( c )
  FROM DUAL;
END;
/

PRINT cur;
```

Comment: thank you, but error is 'length of input buffer is smaller than amount requested'

Comment: the error is: 22921. 00000 -  "length of input buffer is smaller than amount requested"
*Cause:    The buffer length is not big enough to hold the amount of data
           requested.
*Action:   Verify that the number of bytes/characters specified in the
           input amount parameter is not bigger than the number of bytes
           specified in the input buffer length parameter.  Allocate more
           space for the input buffer if necessary.

Comment: Where does it occur in the code? Line number and which code snippet are you running? I cannot replicate this issue with my data so you may need to debug it yourself - add some `DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()` statements in the function to locate where the error occurs if you can't get a line number.

Comment: i tried your first solution on test db and SELECT XMLType( BLOB_TO_CLOB( ADVICE_DOC ) ) AS xml
FROM   advice_document; // error is here